# JavaFX TextArea appendText works in initialize but not elsewhere

Tags: javafx, fxml

Simple enough problem but it's been driving me crazy.

In my program I have a `TextArea`, defined as:

```xml
<TextArea fx:id="output" editable="false" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="200.0" text="Output" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
```

```
@FXML private TextArea output;

...

public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    output.setText("Test"); //Test appears correctly in output
    ...
}

@FXML
public void download() {
    String outputTemplate = templateField.getText();
    String url = urlField.getText();
    System.out.println("Downloading from " + url);
    try {
        Process down = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("youtube-dl -o \"" + outputTemplate + "\" " + url);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(down.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line); //Prints as expected
            output.appendText(line + "\n"); //Has no effect
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to get the text to appear would be great, I've done this before on different programs, just for some reason, this time it's being cantankerous

EDIT: Upon further tinkering, it actually will print out the results, but only after the `Process` ends and it exits the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text shown in the UI changes on a layout pulse. Layout pulses are done on the JavaFX application thread. Event handlers, like your `download` method run on the same thread effectively preventing it from doing any layouting or processing and other events until it completes. This is why you shouldn't block this thread with longrunning tasks, but execute them on a different thread.

Since updates to the UI should be done from the application thread, use `Platform.runLater` to append the text:

```
@FXML
public void download() {
    String outputTemplate = templateField.getText();
    String url = urlField.getText();
    Runnable r  = () -> {
        System.out.println("Downloading from " + url);
        try {
            Process down = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("youtube-dl -o \"" + outputTemplate + "\" " + url);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(down.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line); //Prints as expected
                final String printText = line + "\n";

                // append the line on the application thread
                Platform.runLater(() -> output.appendText(printText));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    };
    // run task on different thread
    Thread t = new Thread(r);
    t.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're doing this in the main thread. So stage can not be updated, until the cycle is finished. Try it in new thread:

```
@FXML
public void download() {
    Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void call() {
            String outputTemplate = templateField.getText();
            String url = urlField.getText();
            System.out.println("Downloading from " + url);
            try {
                Process down = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("youtube-dl -o \"" + outputTemplate + "\" " + url);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(down.getInputStream()));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line); // Prints as expected
                    output.appendText(line + "\n"); // Has no effect
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
    new Thread(task).start();
}
```

Comment: It's not thread safe. From the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html) "modification of live objects must be done on the JavaFX Application Thread". So while it might happen to work on your specific platform, there is no guarantee it will work in general.